# Alinear lista dentro de un div hacia la parte superior

Tags: html, css, position

tengo un menu que esta ocupado dentro de un div, en la cual tengo columnas y cada una con una lista, resulta que la segunda columna tiene una lista solo con dos Item! y justo esta columna es la que me trae problemas ya que se posiciona en la parte inferior y lo que yo necesito es que todas las listas se posicionen en la parte superior. les dejo el codigo.

Codigo html

```
<div class="menu-background">
    <div class="categoria-caja">
        <ul>
          <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 1</a></li>
          <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 2</a></li>
          <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="categoria-caja">
        <ul>
          <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 1</a></li>
          <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="categoria-caja">
       <ul>
         <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 1</a></li>
         <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 2</a></li>
         <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
```

y el siguiente código css.

```
.menu-background{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 0px #888888;;
    width: 48%;
    margin-left: -350px;
    top:180px;
    left:50%;
    padding: 30px;
    z-index: 9998;
    text-align: center;
}

.categoria-caja{
    width: 32%;
    display: flex;
}



.categoria-caja ul>li{

    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #555555;
    width: 87%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Lo que pasa es que al presentar la tabla con las tres columnas, la segunda lista se coloca hacia abajo y necesito que todos esten arriba..

[image: Esta es la forma como sale]

Comment: En el código que publicaste .menu-background tiene display:none; cuando lo mostrás usas display:block o display:flex?

Comment: Solo hago un fadeIn y un fadeOut en java pero ese no es problema, el problema son las listas.

Comment: @KarlosYalta en Java?

Answer (score 1):

Ten en cuenta que para utilizar [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox), `display: flex;` debes aplicarselo al contenedor de los elementos que quieres organizar.

Una solución (y no es la única) puede ser crear un solo contenedor con la clase "categoria-caja" y dentro de este las tres listas. Por ejemplo:

```html
<div class="categoria-caja">
            <ul>
                <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 1</a></li>
                <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 2</a></li>
                <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            
            <ul>
                <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 1</a></li>
                <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 2</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
                <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 1</a></li>
                <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 2</a></li>
                <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chicos logré esto corrigiendo mi css, poniendo en vez de display:none un display:flex.

```
.menu-background{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 0px #888888;;
    width: 48%;
    margin-left: -350px;
    top:180px;
    left:50%;
    padding: 30px;
    z-index: 9998;
    text-align: center;
}
```

y en el html añadirle un atributo con el estilo display: none:

```
<div class="menu-background" style="display:none";>
    <div class="categoria-caja">
        <ul>
          <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 1</a></li>
          <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 2</a></li>
          <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="categoria-caja">
        <ul>
          <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 1</a></li>
          <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="categoria-caja">
       <ul>
         <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 1</a></li>
         <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 2</a></li>
         <li><span class="icon-box"></span><a href="#" target="_blank">item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
```